# color changing while uploading image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, graphics, system.drawing

I am using a method that i got from internet and I customized it a little bit.

it takes a HttpPostedFile from fileUpload and some not necessary parameters and then resize the image and comperise it then saving it in the hosting and returning the location

but after I uploaded the image I found it become a little bit gray and you can see the difference in the two pictures here.

**Real Image:**
[image]

**Uploaded Image**
[image: Uploaded Image]

how I can fix that in my method.

**My Upload Method**

```
public string ResizeImage(HttpPostedFile PostedFile, string destinationfile, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{

    float ratio;

    // Create variable to hold the image
    System.Drawing.Image thisImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(PostedFile.InputStream);

    // Get height and width of current image
    int width = (int)thisImage.Width;
    int height = (int)thisImage.Height;

    // Ratio and conversion for new size
    if (width < maxWidth)
    {
        ratio = (float)width / (float)maxWidth;
        width = (int)(width / ratio);
        height = (int)(height / ratio);
    }

    // Ratio and conversion for new size
    if (height < maxHeight)
    {
        ratio = (float)height / (float)maxHeight;
        height = (int)(height / ratio);
        width = (int)(width / ratio);
    }

    // Create "blank" image for drawing new image
    System.Drawing.Bitmap outImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
    System.Drawing.Graphics outGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(outImage);
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush sb = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);

    outGraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    outGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    outGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    // Fill "blank" with new sized image
    outGraphics.FillRectangle(sb, 0, 0, outImage.Width, outImage.Height);
    outGraphics.DrawImage(thisImage, 0, 0, outImage.Width, outImage.Height);
    sb.Dispose();
    outGraphics.Dispose();
    thisImage.Dispose();

    if (!destinationfile.EndsWith("/"))
        destinationfile += "/";

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(destinationfile)))
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(destinationfile));

    // Save new image as jpg
    string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    outImage.Save(Server.MapPath(destinationfile + filename + ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    outImage.Dispose();

    return destinationfile + filename + ".jpg";
}
```

***EDIT***

I took a print screen so you can see the difference in color between the two picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the images when it comes to color, is that the original image doesn't have a color profile at all, while the processed image has the sRGB color profile.

Depending on the browser, the operating system, and how your screen is calibrated, the images will be shown with slightly different colors. For the image without a color profile, the browser can either assume a color profile for it, or it can display it without any color correction at all. When I view the images in Firefox on my computer that has a color calibrated screen, I actually can't see any color difference at all.

The JPEG encoder has assumed the sRGB color profile when you save the image, which is as good a guess as any other profile when there is no color profile information at all in the original image. You need to upload an image with a color profile to see if the JPEG encoder handles that correctly or not. As long as there is no color profile, there is no right or wrong when it comes to interpreting the color values in the image.

Comment: I still can see the difference in firefox :(

Comment: +1 very well explained. The images appear exactly the same and my significant other noted that maybe the OP had been staring at the computer too long today :)

Comment: LOL yea im working on this website 12+ hours today but you know i asked one of my family and she said they are difference. :D
she said [the real image] is yellow and [uploaded image] is white

Comment: @Ziny: Did you try to upload an image that has a color profile? Could you add the result to the question?